# How to use Breakpoints to change bootstrap columns grid ordering?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, media-queries

I have the html code like this :

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
  <div class="row no-gutters h-100">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6  left">
      Column 1
    <div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6  left">
      Column 2
    <div>
  <div>
<div>
```

How can i change the griding of columns in bootstrap using breakpoints in css to show `Column1` above `Column2` if the screen is less than `720px` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify [grid tiers](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-tiers), for example:

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 720px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 1024px
);

$container-max-widths: (
  sm: 660px,
  md: 720px,
  lg: 960px
);
```

Thus, viewport with width less than 720 will be considered an `sm` and `col-12` will be applied to cells.

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak that using `flex directions`, I am adding an example based on your code sample.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid h-100">
  <div class="row flex-column-reverse flex-md-row no-gutters h-100">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
      Column 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
      Column 2
    </div>
  <div>
<div>
```

Comment: i tried your solution but it doesn’t work.. the `column 2` disappears and can't scroll down