# How can i use breakpoint.value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a site to monitor employees and I want this site to be "responsive", meaning that it works on all devices.

As a simple example:

If you want to make a responsive to "sm, xs" screens, you can do so through this instruction:

```
[theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
            -------------
            //some css code
        }
```

But I had this problem. The problem is when testing the site on the browser. We find that from "xs" to "sm", it is a group of devices, which are:

```
    Moto G4----> size:360
    Galaxy S5 ----> size:360
    Pixel2 ----> size:411
    etc
```

[image]

The question now is how can I address each type of these screens separately,
That is, how can I handle a screen with a size of "411" and so on.

I tried this :

```
  [theme.breakpoints.down(411)]: {
                -------------
                //some css code
            }
```

but it doesn't worksing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Breakpoints to change bootstrap columns grid ordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66981371/how-to-use-breakpoints-to-change-bootstrap-columns-grid-ordering)

Comment: no, I need make this with material ui.

I Edit my Post>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Dcoumentation](https://cssinjs.org/jss-syntax/?v=v10.6.0#objects-based-styles-syntax-for-declaring-style-sheets)

```js
hotpink: {
  '@media (min-width:411px)': {
    color: 'hotpink',
  },
},
```

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return <div className={classes.hotpink}>hello</div>
}
```

If you need to listen to media query values inside your component, you can use [useMediaQuery](https://material-ui.com/components/use-media-query/#usemediaquery).